# String's split returning unexpected value

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("1.1.1".split(".")));
```

This prints out an empty array. What gives?
To me, it should print out "[1, 1, 1]". Instead, it prints out "[]". It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The split method takes a regular expression, so guess what "." matches?

Answer (score 3):

. is wildcard character in regex.

use - `split("\\.")`

Comment: Ya I just figured this out by searching, so I am deleting this question

Comment: @Hank don't do that. Other people might be interested in the question.

Comment: Nevermind, I can't delete it so I guess it shall stay.

Comment: @Hank You cannot delete a question with an upvoted answer, actually.

Comment: @Hank, please try to search for an answer before posting a question next time. I usually google *site:stackoverflow.com java <whatever I'm about to post a question on>*